# Distinct normal launch with push notification Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, push-notification, mpns

hi I have been developing an App for Windows Phone 7 with daily update when start and push notification enable. so far I use 2 types of push notification at the same time ( toast and tile ). since my App need a long time update. so I will have to distinct between normal start ( will update ) and start from push notification ( no update will be allowed ). Now I can distinct for the toast with query string. but when start from tile I can't because I donno how to get the count from the tile of my App.

so the question is "How can I get the count from tile notification ?"

Answer (score 2):

You can query your tile data when the app is launching and look at the Count property, if > 0 it's a launch after notification.

To get your application tile:

```
var tileToFind = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First();
int count = tileToFind.Count;
```

Comment: Good answer. Don't forget that the count of the tile only represents the count when it was last set in code or when the server last delivered a push. For example, the "unread e-mail" count is only valid for as long as it takes Hotmail to tell my phone that I've read all my e-mail messages in the browser on my desktop. In the 5 minutes or so between reading the e-mails on my desktop and Hotmail updating the phone, the count will be invalid. You may want to implement a method for checking the server instead of depending on the Tile count.

Comment: Actually there is no property Count for the Class Microsoft.Phone.Shell.ShellTile. I can only access to property "NavigationUri" and there are method Update, Delete. Is it a problem of my SDK or something else ?

Comment: You are right. In my application I use a Background Agent to update my Tile/Count property and so I set a flag too in a local database which I query at the startup to know if there was an notification.