# How to get number from Tile Notification

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0

When I get any and when I get more than one push messages (so in any cases) this methode shows always "1".

```
  private void Application_Activated(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e)
            {
                List<ShellTile> pinnedtiles = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.ToList();
                MessageBox.Show(pinnedtiles.Count().ToString());

            }
```

How I have testing this: I start my application, than I go into background, sent some push messages, the number of new messages is more than one, than I activate my application and in message box I got the same number - 1 (but on Tile icon I have more)

When I start first my application , before I have recieved any push messages, I have the same result (1)

What I am doing wrong?

**UPDATED:**

In this post it works:

[Distinct normal launch with push notification Windows Phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977836/distinct-normal-launch-with-push-notification-windows-phone-7)

**UPDATED:**
There is no Count property:

```
  MessageBox.Show(ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First().Count.ToString());
```

**UPDATED:**
Is there any other way to get count from Tile?

Comment: I dont understand your question. Do you want to know the total number of tiles or something about a specific tile?

Comment: I want to the total number of tiles

Comment: @revolutionkpi, you always get a value of 1 because the 'Count' method on an 'IList<ShellTiles>'. In other words you are counting the number of active application tiles, rather than the "number" on the top left of the active tile (which is what I assume you're trying to find).

Comment: so how can I count the "number" on the top left of the active tile?

Comment: @revolutionkpi, I think you're going down the wrong path if you're using the Live Tile to count the number of push notifications that your client app has received. I haven't created an app to do this just yet, but I would look at the docs (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202970(v=vs.92).aspx) and re-examine how you client responses to push notifications.

Comment: I am not going the wrong path, I am just trying to get count of unread tile messages to use this in my application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ShellTile does not allow you to read the values only to update them (using [Update](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.shelltile.update%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) method). As someone suggested in the comments above, I would make your app the source of the data rather than trying to read it from the shelltile.

I would do something like this:

ViewModel - Saved to isolated storage on application exit / unload / whenever:

```
public int OutstandingNotification{ get; set;}
```

BackgroundTask for updating the Live tile based on notifications:

```
tile.Update(new StandardTileData { Count = App.ViewModel.OutstandingNotification}
```

Application Load - Loads the ViewModel from isolated storage and displays the value:

```
MessageBox.Show(App.ViewModel.OutstandingNotification.ToString());
```

Comment: How can I have: BackgroundTask for updating the Live tile based on notifications?

Comment: I dont know about Background agents as I havent done any work with them yet. I guessed above. The point is that you have the data stored somewhere other than the ShellTile which you control and can query as you wish.

Comment: There is a great post covering background agents and how to use them to update tiles/show toast by Peter Torr here:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2011/07/11/background-agents-part-1-of-3.aspx